# With React, how to write friendlier and clearer conditional rendering given the following

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React 16 app, I have the following render function:

```
  render() {
    const {
      isLoading,
      leverJobData,
      isApiError
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <Openings.Container>
        <Openings.StyledH4>Open roles:</Openings.StyledH4>

        {isLoading && <h4>Loading...</h4>}

        {!isLoading && isApiError && <h4>Something went wrong. Please try again later!</h4>}

        {!isLoading && !isApiError && leverJobData.length === 0 && (
          <h4>There are no openings at this time.</h4>
        )}

        {!isLoading && !isApiError && leverJobData.length > 0 && (
          <>{this.renderJobOpenings(leverJobData)}</>
        )}
      </Openings.Container>
    );
  }
```

Is there a cleaner way to write the above or is this the right way to do conditional rendering in React?

Comment: You can always extract the render logic to a function. But inside `jsx` I don't see it getting any prettier than that.

Comment: **I think your code is much more readable than the answers, as any answer will try to re-write it with the conditional statement which is more confusing for most of the developers (eslint have a role for that https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary).**

Answer (score 2):

When I have blocks like this, I like to break out the conditions and describe exactly what they're doing. For example:

```js
render() {
  const {
    isLoading,
    leverJobData,
    isApiError
  } = this.state;

  const hasError = !isLoading && isApiError;
  const noJobsAvailable = !isLoading && !isApiError && leverJobData.length === 0;
  const hasJobsAvailable = !isLoading && !isApiError && leverJobData.length > 0;

  return (
    <Openings.Container>
      <Openings.StyledH4>Open roles:</Openings.StyledH4>
      {isLoading && <h4>Loading...</h4>}
      {hasError && <h4>Something went wrong. Please try again later!</h4>}
      {noJobsAvailable && <h4>There are no openings at this time.</h4>}
      {hasJobsAvailable && this.renderJobOpenings(leverJobData)}
    </Openings.Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: You could simplify this even more by removing `isLoading` from the conditions and making two clear branches in the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider wrapping similar conditionals like this:

```
const meow = () => {
  const {
    isLoading,
    leverJobData,
    isApiError
  } = this.state;

  return (
    <Openings.Container>
      <Openings.StyledH4>Open roles:</Openings.StyledH4>
      {
        !isLoading ?
          !isApiError ?
            leverJobData.length > 0 ?
              <>{this.renderJobOpenings(leverJobData)}</> :
              <h4>There are no openings at this time.</h4>
            :
              <h4>Something went wrong. Please try again later!</h4>
          : <h4>Loading...</h4>
      }
    </Openings.Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: I would say: Never nest ternary expressions.

Answer (score -1):

The most readable way to write this structure is to use **State Machines**. That can be accomplished with a `switch` Statement:

```js
const IS_LOADING = 1;
const API_ERROR = 2;
const LEVER_JOB_DATA = 3;

_renderStatus = (status) => {
  switch(currentStatus) {
     case LOADING: 
        return <h4>Loading...</h4>;
     case API_ERROR: 
        return <h4>Something went wrong. Please try again later!</h4>;
     case LEVER_JOB_DATA:
        // inside renderJobsOpenings you handle empty state
        const {leverJobData} = this.state;
        return this.renderJobOpenings(leverJobData);
     default:
        // or make sure to render a proper invalid state information
        return null;
    }
}

render() {
    const {currentStatus} = this.state;
    return (
      <Openings.Container>
       { this._renderStatus(currentStatus) }
      </Openings.Container>
    );
  }
```

Avoid nested ternary operations. It gets really hard to read.

The best thing to handle that is to use the [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook. This way you can have a proper state change in many touch points with a single side-effect call (setState)

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    const { isLoading, isApiError, leverJobData } = this.state;
    const Content = () => {
      if (isLoading) return <h4>Loading...</h4>;
      else if (isApiError) return <h4>Something went wrong. Please try again later!</h4>;
      else if (leverJobData.length === 0) return <h4>There are no openings at this time.</h4>;
      else if (leverJobData.length > 0) return <h2>{this.renderJobOpenings(leverJobData)}</h2>;
    };
    
    return <Content />
  }
}
```

This does add an extra step of the component, but the actual render is a little 'cleaner'.

Comment: Do not create component within a render function, this is going to mess up the update flow (components always recreated instead).

Comment: Good point. But the formatting still is valid. Just move the component out and pass in the state as props.